# Perforce diff sorted by date

Tags: diff, perforce

- How do I get perforce diff's sorted by order in which changes were made .
- can we have output of diff only after certain date .
- Solutions to above output only for certain user, files..

Comment: Try `p4 help diff` and read up on Filespecs then come back if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

You would definitely have to write a tool to do this efficiently, but here's some pointers

**p4 changes** [Documentation](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/changes.html#1048020)

This command allows you to list every changelists that fit with certain criteria such as `-u user` for a specific user, `@date` for everything before date, `@date1,@date2` for anything submitted between `date1` and `date2`, `/depot/location' to retrieve only changelists affecting files in`/depot/location`, etc... check documentation for more.

It will output a list items formatted like this:

```
Change ChangeNumber on Year/Month/Day by User@WorkspaceName 'Shortened Description'
```

Now that you have the changelists, you need to see the details of them, so parse your output from `p4 changes` and then call `p4 describe`.

**p4 describe** [Documentation](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/describe.html#1040665)

This command allows you to get the description of a changelist by providing its ChangeNumber (from our change output).

The output of this command will look something like:

```
Change ChangeNumber by User@WorkspaceName on Year/Month/Day Time
*new line*
*tab*Full Description
*new line*
Affected files ...
*new line*
... //depot/path/file#RevisionNumber operation(add/change/delete...) // repeated for as many files that were in the changelist
```

**p4 diff2** [Documentation](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/diff2.html#1040665)

This command will now allow you to diff two revisions on the depot. You can use flags sur as `-ds` to only have a summary. Not providing a revision number will use the `HEAD` revision.

As an example, I added // test and a new line to a document, testing it against its previous revision gives this kind of output

```
==== //depot/path/file#RevisionNumber (text) - //depot/path/file#2ndRevisionNumber (text) ==== content
2a3,4
> // test
>
```

**p4 diff** [Documentation](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/diff.html#1040665)

`diff` will be very similar to `diff2` but it diffs with the file on the machine, useful if you have pending changes.

This should help you get started!